# Trying to delete a database on Phpmyadmin stops at "Forwarding request"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I made a mysql database called testdb and tried adding data to it from an exported database I administer in another server.

The upload never finishes (even though the file size is 1.5mb). I decide I will delete the tables and reinsert thinking something went wrong at the upload.

Data delete wont go on stopping at "Forwarding request".
Decided I will delete the whole database and re-create it. 
Same story.

I am stuck with a database I can't upload data to, remove data from or delete.

Using wamp server 3.0.6, Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 5.6.25 - MySQL 5.7.14
PHP 5.6.25 for CLI (Command-Line Interface)

I have done the same process on many databases since then and before then.
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried stopping and restarting MYSQL

Comment: Is there any useful info in the MYSQL Error log `wampmanager->MYSQL->Error log`

Comment: I am afraid no. There is no such file but there is a wamp64>logs>mysql which has preaty much nothing in it..

Comment: Also, on RiggsFolly question. I did try that.. Did not work for uploading or viewing the data, only thing I managed with it was to completely delete the database.

Comment: In that case also look at the Windows Event Log. MYSQL writes errors there even before it gets to opening its own log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution to delete the database.

Close phpmyadmin tab, restart the service, reopen phpmyadmin and go straight to Databases tab that is on the top icons. Select the database you want to delete and delete.

Downloaded a new backup of the database from the other server, and recreated database -> uploaded the data.